# ClassLoading under android ics

Tags: android, classloader, ioexception

Are there any restrictions to ClassLoaders under android ICS?

I´m not getting a single example working at all, and I think I´m doing everything right.

For example, this code

```
    DexFile df = new DexFile("/sdcard/test.apk");
    ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader();
    Class clazz = df.loadClass("com/test/LibraryClass", cl);
```

Produces:

> E/dalvikvm﹕ Dex cache directory isn't writable: /data/dalvik-cache
>
> I/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to open or create cache for /sdcard/test.apk (/data/dalvik-cache/sdcard@test.apk@classes.dex)
>
> W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file

The location is correct, the dex file exists.

Answer (score 1):

/data/dalivk-cache has permission of 775. It is not writable directory for others. It is done so for security purpose, so that applications don't modify other applications. It is meant for system installer which unpacks and unzip the dex file contained in apk.

For applications to load external classes, use [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html)

```
DexClassLoader loader = new DexClassLoader("/sdcard/com.example.test.apk", getApplicationInfo().dataDir, null, getClassLoader());
try {
    loader.loadClass("com.example.test.MainActivity");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not load class");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading from the internal storage area, then for API 18 and earlier, you'll need this permission in your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You don't need the above permission starting from API 19 onwards. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) for more info.

Also, instead of hardcoding the path (i.e. "/sdcard/") in your class, I would use this instead:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```